# VW Passat leak. Where is it coming from?

Tags: vw, body-work, water-leak

I have a 2004 VW Passat wagon which has a frustrating leak. We thought it was caused by a leaking door seal, but today we caught it in action.

The car was parked outside overnight in rain. This morning the floor was dry. The car was driven a short distance and parked on a sloping driveway which caused the car to lean to the left (slightly nose up). Within seconds there was about a litre of water in the footwell of the back left seat.

The water was running out of the bottom of the B-pillar between the front and back doors.

Where could this be coming from? Sunroof drain? B-pillar? Sill? It must be holding quite a decent amount of water.

Can anyone familiar with VW Passats tell me if this a known/common fault? If so where is it holding water, and what is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's related to your sunroof.

There is a set of drain going down in the B pillar and one in the A pillar. They drain in the door opening between the two door hinges. Try blowing compress air in the drain (mainly back in your case) and see if that fix the problem. If not the drain main have disconnected from the plug.

You can read more about it here https://www.passatworld.com/forums/b5-garage/226158-questions-regarding-sunroof-drain-tubes.html

also here is a diagram of the sunroof assembly
https://www.passatworld.com/forums/b5-information-base/196712-sunroof-drains-exploded-view.html

Comment: We took the car to our mechanic today and he started  dismantling the interior. Turns out the water is coming through the door. The door was damaged and repaired some time ago and the panel beaters bent an aluminuim shield that fits inside the door lining. As it no longer seals water running into the door runs into the car instead of draining out through the normal drain holes in the door.

Comment: that would have been hard to guess XD. Glad it's fixed now.

Comment: Damn thing still leaks :(

Comment: sorry to hear that :(